# Spring MVC - HTTP status code 400 (Bad Request) for missing field which is defined as being not required

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I have Spring MVC application with this controller method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addNumber(@RequestParam(value="number", required=false) Long number) {
   ...
   return "redirect:/showAll/";
}
```

In my JSP I have a standard HTML form which is posting a value named "number" to the controller method above. However, if I leave out the value (do not enter anything into the text field) and POST the data to the controller, before the controller method is called my browser shows

```
HTTP Status 400 - Required Long parameter 'number' is not present
```

although the controller method annotation clearly defines the "number"-parameter as **not** required.

Does anyone have a slight idea of what could be going on?

Thank you.

PS: The exception that is being thrown is as follows:

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Long parameter 'number' is not present
```

**EDIT: This is a Spring 3.2.3.RELEASE bug ( [see here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10592)). With version 3.1.4.RELEASE I do not have this problem anymore.**

Comment: It is saying that post request not contain name parameter. Cross check with firebug fire fox.

Comment: Sorry, this is a typo carried over from my real world test app. It should be "number" as it is in the (edited) example above now.

Comment: It's strange. I just tested with 3.2.0.RELEASE and 3.2.3.RELEASE and in both cases your code works as expected.

Comment: Indeed, this is strange.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I came across the same situation, and this happens when your parameter is present in the request with an empty value.

That is, if your POST body contains "number=" (with empty value), then Spring throws this exception. However, if the parameter is not present at all in the request, it should work without any errors.

Comment: Yeah, this is a total bug right? Still getting this issue in 2014. Is it supposed to do this?

Comment: This happens in Spring 4.1, too. However, if you set the `defaultValue` in the `RequestParam` annotation, no exception is thrown.

Comment: In my code, I am receiving a JSON object and the problem was that does not exists a default constructor in this object. After create it, works fine!

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that some of the headers in a request I was sending with Postman were not present (were unchecked):

[image]

When I checked back the `Content-Length` header, the request worked fine (200 OK response).